zeep is assigning the wrong data type to two columns in my soap API request
I am using zeep to perform soap api requests in python, which is working pretty well on 3/4 of the api calls. On one of the calls, all of the columns but 2 are coming in correctly. Those 2 columns are coming in with the wrong data type and I'm worried that is screwing up my data.
I am using zeep to perform soap api requests in python as follows (the start time is actually the latest time I have in my dataset, but I've hard-coded a time here):
`wsdl_url = "https://webservices.chargepoint.com/cp_api_5.1.wsdl"
client = Client(wsdl_url, wsse=UsernameToken(cpusername, cppassword))

def FleetUsageAPIcall(client):
    eastern_tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
    now = datetime.now(ZoneInfo('America/New_York'))
    fleetusagedf = pd.DataFrame()
    tStart = datetime(2024, 5, 15, 00, 00, 00, tzinfo=eastern_tz)
    while tStart < now:
        tEnd = tStart + timedelta(days=10)
        searchQuery = {'fromTimeStamp': tStart, 'toTimeStamp': tEnd}
        fleetUsageData = client.service.getFleetUsageData(searchQuery)
        fleetusagedf = pd.concat([fleetusagedf, pd.DataFrame(helpers.serialize_object(fleetUsageData.fleetUsageData))])
        tStart = tStart + timedelta(days = 10)
        if tStart > now: break
    return fleetusagedf

fleetusagedf = FleetUsageAPIcall(client)`

BUT when I run that, the df I get is great except two columns, chargingTime and sessionDuration, are datetime.time type, when they should be timedelta types. I could just change them to strings and then to timedelta, I guess, but I'm worried that they are actually the wrong data because of the being loaded in the wrong type, because on some of them I get a warning "ValueError: hour must be in 0..23" so maybe the value isn't loading? The rest of the columns are coming in correctly.
